# selenium maven junit - 2 different times reported when getting error "Timed out receiving message from renderer"

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, timeout

I'm running a junit selenium maven test suite with chromedriver 111.0.5563.19 and browser version 111.0.5563.64 and java version "1.8.0_361" (versions haven't change in months/yrs). We're using, in an "abstract" class which handles setting up all the browser options etc:

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

which I know is working because if I set "pageLoadTimeout" to 1 second I get an error message like:

```
Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.286
```

What I can't figure out is these messages in the log file:

```
INFO 2023-10-16T06:29:18.432983853Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": [1697437747.890][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
INFO 2023-10-16T06:29:18.433116925Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": [1697437747.894][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
INFO 2023-10-16T06:29:18.433468937Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": [1697437747.898][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
INFO 2023-10-16T06:29:18.434499925Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
INFO 2023-10-16T06:29:18.478308964Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
INFO 2023-10-16T10:57:57.332725497Z Step #1 - "dcs automation test": [ERROR] Run 1: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
```

The 300 is obvious, but can't figure out where the 600 is coming from or how to manage it. The 600 error has recently reared it's ugly head and is occurring far more frequently which is causing our tests to run far longer than they should.

I think the 300 is when we use

```
driver.navigate().to(url)
```

and looks like the 600 is happening when we click a link and are waiting for the page to load.

Is that correct? and is there a way to change that timeout?

I will add that this is not a driver issue as running on local using chromedriver v. 118.0.5993.70 produces similar errors

Any help/thoughts greatly appreciated.

Have also been encountering a lot of hangs that started about the same time which I've posted in another thread here:
[selenium maven junit - 2 different times reported when getting error "Timed out receiving message from renderer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376486/selenium-maven-junit-2-different-times-reported-when-getting-error-timed-out)