# maven selenium cucumber junit - test suite inexplicably started to hang

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

We're running a maven selenium junit cucumber test suite (approximately 250 test cases). We recently started getting "hangs" of 4+ hours for no obvious reason. Nothing has changed re dependencies, versions etc.

We have page load and script timeouts:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In the log we get:

```
Feature: Ad placement on web site.There should be one ad after every list on the homepage Time elapsed: 21,616.202 s <<< FAILURE! (that's 6+ hrs)
```

There's nothing in the "regular" logs that indicates a problem. It just hangs and then continues on so don't know if running in debug or verbose mode would help. Would it help?

We've tried:

- running the test suite using code prior to the problem
- setting the pageloadstrategy to both eager and none
- running on an previous artifact prior to the problem
- upgrading chromedriver to v. 119 ...

Don't want to get too detailed but wondering if anyone might be able to give me any ideas on how to figure out what's going on.  Would be open to suggestions to install something that monitors the tests that might help narrow down the problem.

The "hangs" happen every run, but there's no discernible pattern to them (not the same test case, not within a specific time period, not the same domain). I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

I read somewhere that 3rd party scripts might cause selenium to hang especially google analytics. Could it be?

Been grappling with the problem for the last week or so and getting pretty frustrated so any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

We've also been encountering a lot of `Timeout received from renderer` problems which I've posted in a different thread [selenium maven junit - 2 different times reported when getting error "Timed out receiving message from renderer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376486/selenium-maven-junit-2-different-times-reported-when-getting-error-timed-out)

```
java version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_361-b09)
chromedriver version: 111.0.5563.64
selenium version: 3.141.59 (orignal version 3.9.1 was incorrect)
cucumber/junit version: 4.8.1
```